# Enable CORS for all APIs with Spring MVC

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, cors

How to "easily" configure Spring MVC so that every request to any API in my application returns the magic CORS header?

For example, with a `@ControllerAdvice` or using a common AOP advice.

Comment: Have you looked at: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Use Tomcat's CORS filter http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve with this steps:

1. Add Maven Dependency

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
>   <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
>   <version>2.2.1</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

2. Add this parameters in web.xml

   ```
   <filter>
   <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

   <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>

   <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
       <param-value>*</param-value>
   </init-param>

   <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
       <param-value>false</param-value>
   </init-param>

   <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
       <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS</param-value>
   </init-param>

   <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
       <param-value>*</param-value>
   </init-param>

   <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>

   <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
       <param-value>3600</param-value>
   </init-param>   
   </filter>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

One of the way of doing it can be use of Interceptor classes as below:

- I am not implementing while interceptor setting for brevity of code.

Lets we have interceptor method for all URL's like below:

```
 public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {

       request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/jsonp");    

       //OR

       response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/jsonp");
       response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
       response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
       response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
       response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
}
```

**We have to configure interceptor only to cater for Controller methods.**

**JSONP** is one of the preferred format for CORS communication.